# GIMP Plugin is Missing

Tags: gimp

I recently noticed that my GIMP installation has lost the "National Geographic" plug-in. Is there a way to get it back?

[image: Details of Installation]

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? How did you install GIMP? Please add output of `which gimp`, `apt-cache policy gimp`, `snap list | grep -i gimp`, `flatpak list | grep -i gimp` to the question.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04. GIMP was pre-installed. I had updated Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 and then to 20.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [search results on packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=national-geographic.scm) you need to (re)install deb-package named `gimp-plugin-registry` by

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gimp-plugin-registry
```

Then reboot to apply changes.

Comment: I had to restart my computer to get back all the plug-ins. Thanks.